# Using python to query sqlite3 database. Fetchone() returns real value but python returns a TypeError: NoneType

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlite

I am trying to get the maximum session_id from my database so I can record new values with an incremented session_id. I am using this to group records in my database together.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('../data.db')
c = conn.cursor()
session = c.execute("SELECT session_id FROM data WHERE session_id=(SELECT MAX(session_id) FROM data)")
print session
print session.fetchone()[0]
if session.fetchone()[0] == 5:
    print "HERE"
return session.fetchone()[0]
```

This is what the terminal prints out.

```
sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x7f43cd2f2a40
5
...
    if session.fetchone()[0] == 5:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I double checked my SQL select statement in terminal and I am getting five there. The console is printing a five and yet I am getting a TypeError.

Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can only iterate over the fetch result of `sqlite3.Cursor` once. You should store the result of `session.fetchone()` to an object and then check the object's value